# select dropdown then show text box in flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I'm new utilising Flutter, and I'd like to know how to display a text box based on what the user chooses from a drop-down menu, for example, if the drop-down menu has options of burgers, vegetables, and fruits.

So, once the user chooses burger, the app will provide a text box with the message, "Do not eat that much."  then the user will click okay and will close the text box

Thank you and I hope you can understand.

Comment: You can use dialog for *"Do not eat that much."* Can you include your code-snippet that you;ve tried so far?

Comment: Hello Yeasin, I didnt tried anything yet, but i was looking for an example but i can not find anything

Comment: You can check [DropdownButton-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)

Comment: but how can i add the popupdialog depending on the selected dropdown

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this snippet But must check [`DropdownButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html)

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: DFR(),
    ),
  );
}
class DFR extends StatefulWidget {
  DFR({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DFR> createState() => _DFRState();
}

class _DFRState extends State<DFR> {
  String? selected;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          DropdownButton<String?>(
            items: ["burgers", "vegetables", "fruits"]
                .map(
                  (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    child: Text(e),
                    value: e,
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (v) async {
              if (v == "burgers") {
                await showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      content: Text("Do not eat that much."),
                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text("Ok"),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
              selected = v;
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
          Text(selected ?? ""),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are a start Yeasin, thank you very much